# change Tile background color by Start Screen Color

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, background-color

I am developing a Windows 8 Metro UI app.

How can I set my app Tile background to Start Menu Color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am fairly certain you cannot programmatically access the Start screen color programmatically, though I cannot seem to find a clear reference to that newer than the Release Preview.

You *can* set the tile background color explicitly via the app manifest[image]

Comment: yeah, by the way I think that it is possible to do this.

Comment: 'cos some of the original windows apps such as Calendar do this.

Comment: confirmed with one of the Windows 8 Program Manager's that there is NO API to access the Start screen color scheme. Tiles for desktop apps that are present on the Start Screen do reflect the Start screen accent color, but that is nothing you have control of.

Comment: The Background Color for A Windows Metro-style application can be changed by editing the Background color property inside the Package.appxmanifest file from within Solution Explorer, in Visual Studio 2012 RC. My problem is, how do I ensure that my Tile's Background color always matches the color scheme of the Start Screen in Windows 8? That'll be a HUGE turn off for any app/customer.

Comment: Is there a "Default" color for a Tile's bg color? Leaving it blank is not an option; since VS won't let you.