# Change the App Tile Background Color Programmatically

Tags: windows, cordova, uwp, startmenu

I'm developing an application. I want my deployed/installed application's tile synchronized to the User's background color. There are some answers([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12788004/2637261), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240775/2637261)) to this question saying that I can't achieve this. But how the other apps can achieve this? Like these apps.

[image]

I'm trying to leave a blank to the background color field on VS, however I get an error when I do.

[image]

Any thoughts and comments are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your tile background color to `transparent`. Then it'll automatically use the accent color the user has selected in Windows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Andrew Bares solves this issue. This answer is for `Ionic Framework Cordova` project. Just add this line to **config.xml** under the plaform block of windows.

```
<preference name="BackgroundColor" value="transparent" />
```